# particles are blinking for no apparent reason

Tags: particles, emission

I have a glass-like shape with a particle emitter inside and a few forcefields to direct particles. That works well. But I can't understand why the emission of particles seems to be blinking or reset randomly?

[image: animation1]

This only occurs when rendering, both in Cycles and Eevee, but not in preview mode...
Here is a screenshot of the normals as well as one of the material bsdf

[image]

Here's the blend file
[image]

Comment: Have you enabled *Motion Blur*?

Comment: Looks like you have refraction and possibly something strange going on with normals. Can you share your material nodes?

Comment: @Blunder No it's not enabled so far. Do you think it would solve the problem ?

Comment: @RichSedman I checked the normals on the tetrahedron and all 4 seem to be pointing in the right direction. I added a picture on the post with what you asked for

Comment: I can’t seem to replicate that in Cycles using Blender 3.00. What version are you using? Can you provide exact steps to recreate it or ahare your .blend file?

Comment: @RichSedman The blend file has been added. I'm using Blender 2.91 at the moment

Comment: Could be a total internal reflection issue.  Try raising Total, Glossy, and Transparent bounces under render settings -> light paths

Comment: Ray strikes on the backfacing side of a Glass BSDF surface are glossy bounces

Comment: @JeffS I can't replicate your flickering but I did notice that you've got duplicated geomety, where each face of the tetrahedron is made up two mesh faces. Such duplicated geometry can cause 'z-fighting' which can cause unexpected behaviour. It is feasible that that is the cause of your problem so try selecting your mesh, going into Edit mode and removing the duplicate faces - you can do this in your case by selecting one Vertex/Edge/Face and then pressing 'L' a few times to select any connected geometry, then 'x' to delete it.

Comment: @Blunder I've tried enabling motion blur but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @AllenSimpson I've tried setting all light bounces options up to 100 but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @RichSedman I've deleted duplicate faces as you suggested, but along with all other suggestions listed above, it didn't work (Also, I only have this issue at render, not in preview)

Comment: @JeffS sorry, I missed your first reply. The motion blur can cause glitches under certain circumstances. But this is not the cause here. It's the particles. You need to bake them, see the answer below.

Comment: @Blunder I've done all as you suggested (bake particles, recalculate normals properly, removed all duplicated vertices, give the camera a focus object, and even upgrade to blender 3) but the blinking is still occuring...
Never gives me any problem at preview though... only at render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution almost by accident. Apparently, I have an image sequence already loaded from a previos render test, and it interfered with the proper render of the animation. As soon as I deleted it and re-exported, the issue was gone

Answer (score 1):

The blinking is caused by the particles that collapse at several frames (28, 54, 96, 98, etc) for some reason.

To prevent this glitch in the final animation **bake the particle simulation first**. This is done in the *Particle Settings > Cache* of the *tétrèdre intérieur* object. Then it renders without flickering in Cycles and Eevee.

---

Side notes: The objects in the attached blend file have flipped normals and duplicated vertices as mentioned in the comments. You should correct them first.
Secondly, the camera needs a *Focus Object* for the *Depth of Field* setting else there will be nothing rendered.